# How can I access ContactsContract Profile?

Tags: android

I tried to read the complete profile information such a (Full name, phone, adresse, mail .... ).

I have searched everywhere for a good example code. I tried many ways (Uri => Cursor) to access the Profile.
At this time I can fetch just the Full name (of the Profile contact), nothing more.

I can fetch data of other contacts using an Intent, sending to the Contacts app, BUT I CAN'T READ THE PROFILE CONTACT (JUST FULL NAME).

I have added the READ_PROFILE permission in the manifest file.

With the following code I get the Full Name (I can also access first and last name separately ):

```
Uri uriProfile = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor cursorProfile = this.getContentResolver().query(uriProfile,
                    null, null, null, null);
String projection = Profile.DISPLAY_NAME;
String profileName = cursorProfile.getString(cursorProfile.getColumnIndex(projection);
```

But when I use this the following projection to get Phone Number, it returns an error and the app stops working:

```
String projection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: what does `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` show on the `logcat`?

Comment: @MarcoFerrari Now I haven't any error, but it doesn't matter what projection I use, I always have the Name. Do you have some solution for me to read_profile

Comment: @pskink what do you mean by DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor? Where I get this, how it will help me

Comment: what does calling `android.database.DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()` show on the `logcat`?

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry, I'm really beginner at this tech. I have used DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursorProfile), Is this what you mean? 
Where I will found the logcat? I'm usind Android Studio on Windows

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@3554b5c1
0 {
    data1=PNom NOM
}
1 {
   data1=01 23 45 67 89
}
2 {
 data1=test@test.com
}
3 {
 data1=1 Rue Marcel
Paris 75000
FRANCE 
}
<<<<<
Thank you dude. I'm interesting at this information, how I could get them. I just got the PNom NOM

Comment: you have only one column in your Cursor: its impossible to find out what kind of data it has, you need at least to add `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE` column

Comment: Hello. I am sorry but can you just write me some code how I can get the data seen in the logcat using MINETYPE. I'm searching from yesterday how to use it and I can't find it. The thing is I'm not understanding how all this work.

Comment: And how can you see that I have one column. Is it because of all data are data1? What does the the number before { mean ? 0{ 1{ 2{?

Comment: just use `this.getContentResolver().query(uriProfile, null, null, null, null);` with null `projection` (second parameter)

Comment: `What does the the number before { mean ?` see [this](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#500)

Comment: Thank you dude, you were very helpful

Comment: Can you please take a look to my answer, and if it's ok approve it. I need some reputation

Comment: Thank you, 1 comment for a badge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using this code:

1. Get an URI Profile
2. Crate a cursor pointing to the URI content with null projection. Because for the profile, data are saved differently than a normal contact.
3. Point the cursor to the wanted data using MIMETYPE.

`Uri uriProfile = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor cursorProfile = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uriProfile,
                        null, null, null, null);
String cursorProfile_MIMIETYPE = cursorProfile.getString(cursorProfile.getColumnIndex("MIMETYPE"));`